# Eclipse RCP: Unresolved Requirement

Tags: eclipse, dependencies, rcp

I have two local plugin projects in eclipse, both maven projects.

1. AvgPowerTool
2. AvgPowerCommon

AvgPowerTool is dependent on AvgPowerCommon (It uses classes from AvgPowerCommon).

When I run the application and try to instantiate a class from AvgPowerCommon the application exits with an exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No application id has been found.
```

Above it, in the log I see:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.app 0 0 2015-06-02 12:08:10.113
!MESSAGE Product AvgPowerTool.product could not be found.

!ENTRY AvgPowerTool 2 0 2015-06-02 12:08:10.164
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: AvgPowerTool [208]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: AvgPowerCommon
```

This is how the required plugins in AvgPowerTool's plugin.xml look:
[image: Required Plugins]

What can I do to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Show us the full contents of the plugin.xml

Comment: http://pastebin.com/dKVZ0LAC

Comment: If you are running this using 'Run > Eclipse Application' check the 'Run Configuration' and make sure both your plugins are included

Comment: Thanks, adding the plugin under run configurations solved it.
If you add an answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running an RCP using 'Run > Eclipse Application' you need to make sure that all the required plugins are checked in the 'Run Configuration' for the application (on the Plugins tab).

If you subsequently build the RCP using an xxx.product file you must list all the required plugins (or features) in the product file.